# Выбор наследника div'а

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть:

```
<form id="formtabs" name="formtabs">
<div><input type="radio" name="nametab" id="nametab" value="lastmaterials" /> <h3>Материалы</h3></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="nametab" id="nametab" value="lastphotos" /> <h3>Фотографии</h3></div>
<div><input type="radio" name="nametab" id="nametab" value="lastwork" /> <h3>Портфолио</h3></div>
</form>
```

Хочу по нажатии на **#formtabs div** изменять значение checked в input:radio, который внутри него.

Есть такой вариант, но он не работает:

```
$('#formtabs div').click(function(){
    $('this').has('input').val('checked','checked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, во-первых, id-вещь уникальная для DOM. Так что замените "nametab".
Во-вторых, переключатель radio только 1 элемент может сделать выбранным. Хочется, чтобы при клике выбирался следующий?

Comment: Нет, хочу нажать на div, и выбрался элемент который внутри него, нажал на следующий div, с прошлого checked убрался, а на этом встал.
Примитивная вроде задачка, а не знаю как добраться до ребёнка дива.

Comment: $(this).children('input')
Нашёл что он так получает доступ, но почему-то не происходит его checked

Comment: Проблема решена!

Answer (score 1):

Замените div на label и уберите javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Да, правильно. Фильтр has() выбирает не вложенный элемент (в Вашем случае переключатель), а элемент, содержащий его. Этот фильтр выбирает все дивы, которые содержат input. Поэтому и не получалось: ибо для div, что содержит переключатель, нельзя установить значение checked. А вот так нельзя?

```
$('#formtabs div').click(function(){
   $(this).find('input').attr('checked', checked);
});
```

Или так же воспользоваться val() для изменения состояния переключателя.